# Intellij IDEA cannot resolve React Native import

Tags: intellij-idea, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

[image]

The React import is ok, but other import can not used in autocompletion.

If I import as `import Text from 'react-native'`, this can be resolve correctly, but this is incorrect import.So I assume IDE will resolve symbol by lookup import Class name only, The question is how can I work around this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem occurs because of a tricky way react-native modules are defined. I'd suggest using typescript community stubs to solve the issue: `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`, press `Download`, then choose 'react-native' from the stubs list

Comment: @lena I'll find you and give you a cookie!

Answer (score 8):

I use Webstorm 2017.2 and I experienced this error. I tried various solutions, and following solution was worked on my IDE.

**Step 1:** *This step is optional, but I did it.* Remove all of the Webstrom preferences. Please check document for related folders: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-and-ide-settings.html

**Step 2:** Remove .idea file in the project directory.

**Step 3:** Select React JSX under *Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript*.
[image: Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript]

**Step 4:** Download and select react-native under *Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries*.
[image: Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries]

**Step 5:** Invalidate Caches / Restart...

[image: Invalidate Caches / Restart...]

[image: Final]

Comment: I am using Flow for JavaScript language version, any idea how to make this to work in that case?

Comment: Step 4 alone did it for me, so you can keep flow

Comment: Step 5 alone did it for me, so you can keep flow

Comment: I'm using flow. And, this didn't work for me, do you know how to use Flow in Javascript language and also react native?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, go to:

> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript

and then where it says `JavaScript language version`, choose in the drop down `ReactJSX`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install flow-typed globally. example: $ npm install -g flow-typed
2. flow-typed create-stub react-native
3. open /flow-typed/npm/react-native-vx.x.x.js
4. Copy and paste the entire following code below into react-native.xxx.js.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lelandrichardson/c037f46885af67ceb447091c908d1471/raw/829a0e311ce619bbb224cf68780a16753feaf2b6/react-native.js

P.S. This is the setting when the react-native library component/type cannot be found when designating js as the flow type in the intelliJ platform.